# (PowerShell) How to give a ZIP permissions to allow user to edit directly after downloading from Azure Blob

Tags: powershell, azure, zip, blob

Good morning friends,

I've been writing a script in PowerShell to replace our current manual process to deploy our application to Azure Blob Storage in a ZIP folder during the Build Process in VS. I'm about done, but I've run into this issue:

When the ZIP that I upload to Azure is downloaded by anyone, the ZIP cannot be manipulated without having to extract the files first. This is something the current process is able to accomplish and I don't know how (The current process was written in C# and is done through a GUI). It needs to be editable via the ZIP because the current Updater is set to manipulate the ZIP without the extraction first.

So the initial question is: How do I set permissions on a ZIP archive that will follow it to Azure Blob Storage and then when it's downloaded on a client's machine that allow it's contents to be manipulated (The error itself at this time is that it cannot delete a file in a child folder) without extraction?

Currently, to ZIP my folder up, I use this process:

```
$src = "$TEMPFOL\$testBuildDrop"
$dst = "$TEMPFOL\LobbyGuard.zip"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" )
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($src, $dst)
```

and then push it to blob with:

```
set-azurestorageblobcontent -Container test -blob "LobbyGuard.zip" -file "$TEMPFOL\LobbyGuard.zip" -context $storageCreds -force
```

I've tried to set permissions on the folder prior to upload using

```
$getTEMPFOLACL = Get-ACL $TEMPFOL
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", "FullControl", "Allow")
$getTEMPFOLACL.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
```

Which works on the current local file, but once downloaded, the permissions on the file are set as
Owner: BUILTIN\Adminstrators    Access: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow FullControl

Which is exactly the same permissions as the file that's downloaded from the current process. I'm not understanding what I'm missing here to make this work.

If necessary I can provide the DL link to our blob to show the current manual processes folder that can be manipulated IN the ZIP vs. My Scripts ZIP that cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Try unblocking the file after downloading, ie

```
Unblock-File C:\path\yourDownloaded.zip
```

Comment: The command goes through successfully but didn't seem to change anything in regards to my ability to modify certain contents. I've done more digging and I'm about to Edit my post accordingly to my current findings.